# smtpClient.SendAsync: The email never arrives C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-3.5, smtpclient, sendasync

```
SmtpClient Client = new SmtpClient(SMTPClientHostName, 25)
{
      EnableSsl = true,
      Timeout = 30000,
      DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
      UseDefaultCredentials = false,
      Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SenderEmailAddress, SenderEmailAddressPassword)
};

Object Object = MailMessage;

Client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SMTPClient_SendCompleted);

Client.SendAsync(MailMessage, Object);
```

I'm trying to send an email via SendAsync. It never ever arrives.

The event:

```
private static void SMTPClient_SendCompleted(object Sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs AsyncCompletedEvent)
{
   MailMessage MailMessage = AsyncCompletedEvent.UserState as MailMessage;
}
```

It's been *ten* minutes since I sent it.
The message *does* arrive with Send.

What's wrong here?

UPDATE: My code contained using; after I removed it, the emails started arriving. Does anyone know *why*?

Comment: What is the message you get? Does it work with client.Send()?

Comment: Is GMail involved?

Comment: Which email service you are using to send email??. I mean port number,email-address,user-name and password

Comment: @SouvikGhosh It works with client.Send(), but the code contained "using".
After I removed the usings, the emails started arriving.

Does someone know why?